# Python - Big For Loop

Tags: python, database, loops, for-loop

I'm computing a very big for cycle and i'll try to explain how does it works. There are 4320 matrices (40x80 each) that have been taken from a matlab file.
This loop takes a matrix per time: it assign to each value the right value of H and T. Once finished, it pass to the next matrix and so on.
The dataframe created is then written on a csv file needed for the creation of a database for the wave energy converters productivity.
The problem is that this code is running since 9 days and it is at half on the total computations..Is there any way to drastically reduce the computational time?

```python
indice_4 = 0
configuration_id=-1
n_configurations=4320            
for z in range(0,n_configurations,1): #iteration on all the configurations
    print(z)
    power_matrix=P_mat[z]
              
    energy_wave_period_converted = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['energy_wave_period']) 
              
    H_start=0.25
    H_end=10
    H_step=0.25
    T_start=3
    T_end=17
    T_step=0.177
    y=T_start

    relative_direction = int(direc[z])
    if relative_direction==0:         
        configuration_id = configuration_id + 1
        print(configuration_id)
    r=0 #r=row
    c=0 #c=column
    while y <= T_end: 
        energy_wave_period= float('%.2f'%y) 
        x=H_start #initialize on the right wave haights
        r=0 
        while x <= H_end:
            significant_wave_height= float('%.2f'%x)
            average_power=float('%.2f'%power_matrix[r,c])
            new_line_4 = pd.Series([indice_4 , configuration_id, significant_wave_height , energy_wave_period ,relative_direction ,average_power] , index =['id','configuration_id','significant_wave_height','energy_wave_period','relative_direction','average_output_power'])
            seastate_productivity = seastate_productivity.append([new_line_4], ignore_index=True)                                                                                                                       
            indice_4= indice_4 + 1
            r=r+1
            x=x+H_step
        c=c+1
        y = y + T_step

seastate_productivity.to_csv('seastate_productivity.csv',index=False,sep=';')
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main things slowing your code down is that you do pandas operations in an iteration. Specifically using pd.Series and pd.DataFrame.append in the loop (which runs for over 12 million times) really slows you down. When using pandas you should really aim to vectorize your operations (meaning performing operations in batch). When I tried your original code every iteration took about 4 seconds, but the time increased gradually. When removing the pd.append every iteration only took 0.5 seconds, and when removing the pd.Series it dropped even more.

I did some improvements by saving the data in lists and later to a dataframe in one go, which took about 2 minutes to run till completion on my laptop:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate random data for testing
P_mat = np.random.rand(4320,40,80)
direc=np.random.rand(4320)


H_start=0.25
H_end=10
H_step=0.25
T_start=3
T_end=17
T_step=0.177

indice_4 = 0
configuration_id=-1
n_configurations=4320


data = []
# Time it
t0 = time.perf_counter()
for z in range(n_configurations):
    power_matrix=P_mat[z]

    print(z)

    y=T_start

    relative_direction = int(direc[z])
    if relative_direction==0:
        configuration_id = configuration_id + 1
    r=0 #r=row
    c=0 #c=column
    while y <= T_end:
        energy_wave_period= float('%.2f'%y)
        x=H_start #initialize on the right wave haights
        r=0
        while x <= H_end:
            significant_wave_height= float('%.2f'%x)
            average_power=float('%.2f'%power_matrix[r,c])
            # Save data to list
            new_line_4 = [indice_4 , configuration_id, significant_wave_height , energy_wave_period ,relative_direction ,average_power]
            data.append(new_line_4) # Append to create a list of lists
            indice_4= indice_4 + 1
            r=r+1
            x=x+H_step
        c=c+1
        y = y + T_step



# Make dataframe from list of lists
seastate_productivity = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,columns =['id','configuration_id','significant_wave_height','energy_wave_period','relative_direction','average_output_power'])
# Save data
seastate_productivity.to_csv('seastate_productivity.csv',index=False,sep=';')

# Print time it took
print("Done in:",time.perf_counter()-t0)
```

You could probably still optimize this solution, by moving the rounding from the loop to outside, by rounding the pandas columns. Also, since you are only moving data around, there is probably also a completely vectorized solution (without a loop) but this is probably sufficient for you.

A way to find out what the issue is with slow code is by timing portions of code. You can use the timeit module, or the time module like I used. You can then isolate lines of code, and run them and analyse the performance.

Comment: You saved my time for real! I tried and it runs in less than 2 min. Unbelievable. My computer was running since 2 weeks and it was at half of the iterations. Thanks again for the time saving and for the tips!!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [numpy](https://numpy.org/). Using numpy's matrix operations you should be able to reduce computation time.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The point is that i do no matrix operations, only extraction of values from the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to dig also into concurrent.futures.
It specifically enables to run parallel tasks and reduce run time.

You need to convert your code into a function and then call it into the async func, each element at a time.

*The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables.
The asynchronous execution can be performed with threads, using ThreadPoolExecutor, or separate processes, using ProcessPoolExecutor.*

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

this is a scolastic example

```
import concurrent.futures

    nums = range(10)

def f(x):
    return x * x
def main():
    print([val for val in map(f, nums)])

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print([val for val in executor.map(f, nums)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```